# How to update expired Certificate for Windows IOT

Tags: visual-studio-2017, certificate, driver, windows-10-iot-core

In our BSP all drivers are test signed currently with whatever certificates are supplied in Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\10\tool\certificates folder. Some of these certificates expired 2/1/2022 and now PackageGen fails and we can no longer build an FFU. Where do I find the new certificates? I already tried [Update for Windows OEM HAL Extension](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-windows-oem-hal-extension-test-cert-2017-test-only-test-certificate-851dd12a-b53c-0d2e-0f03-83e770f2677f) but this does not fix our build issue. I am not experienced with how certificates work or what to do. Can anyone help? We use Visual Studio 2017 for building our BSP.